# Having a max value on a gauge, not affected by filters

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a gauge, which when I filter it, the max value doesn't change.

From my table, Table1, I have two fields, a CalendarDate and a BudgetAmount.

If I click on a month in the CalendarDate, I would like the Max value in the gauge to stay as the sum of all the BudgetAmount.

I created a measure as MaxBudgetAmount = CALCULATE(ALL(Table1[BudgetAmount])), but when I put this as the max value in my gauge, I get the following error:

Error Message:
MdxScript(Model) (4, 72) Calculation error in measure 'Table1'[MaxBudgetAmount]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

What am I currently doing wrong?

Comment: This is the expected behavior you cannot return ALL in the table . it will return multiple values. measure should return only one value. Instead of ALL use MAX int the measure.

Comment: Thanks, this will still not give me the sum of all the values in the BudgetAmount though will it, and it still gets filtered if I click on a month in a calendar date

Comment: Unfilter the visuals from month